# How to only run certain lines of a long Stata do file code? (e.g. lines 30-3200)

Tags: stata

I have a very, very long do file which runs different sets of commands every 800 lines or so. (Total about 8000 lines).

It is very cumbersome to select, for example, lines 30-3200 every time to get the code to run. Is it possible to write a command which runs only a segment of a particular code? And possibly multiple segments? e.g. run line 30-3200 and then 4800-5400.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you simply split the do-file in several do-files?

Answer (score 2):

I typically take one of two approaches to this:

1. For a big project, split the analysis into separate files (e.g. a `clean.do` file to prepare data, a `stats.do` file for summary stats, an `analysis.do` file for regressions, ...). Then, create something like a `build.do` file that uses the `include` command to run the other files:

   ```
   // build.do - Run the full analysis
   include clean.do
   include stats.do
   include analysis.do
   ```

   You can then re-run selected parts of the pipeline by typing `include file.do` from the command prompt.
   Splitting the analysis into separate files like this is also a good idea if you're using source control and collaborating with others.
2. You could have one file that takes options for running parts of the code:

   ```
   args run_a run_b

   if `run_a' == 1 {
       // run the part A code ...
   }

   if `run_b' == 1 {
       // run the part B code ...
   }
   ```

   You then specify the parts of the code to run by passing arguments to the script. For example, `do file.do 1 0` would run part A only. This method might become hard to manage with big files; imagine trying to remember what 10 different arguments do.

Personally, I prefer method 1. Keep the do files short and give them logical names as a way to organize the code. Method 1 might also make it easier to find and re-use code in other projects.